# I want to find the user who is doing most physical reads to the hard-disk and kill that user

Tags: oracle-xe

I want to find the user who is doing most physical reads to the hard-disk and kill that user. Can I have a SQL/PL script to do that in oracle xe?

Comment: Upvoting for the aggressive wording of the question ;).

Comment: Can you please help me out writing this piece of sql statement.

Comment: I have days like that too. . .

Comment: No, but Colonel Mustard can do that with a lead pipe in the conservatory.